# Django - Using PostGIS database with PostgreSQL database, do I need 2 databases?

Tags: django, geodjango, django-postgresql

I'm currently using a single PostgreSQL database, with standard settings.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': password,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

My question is, can I keep using the default postgres setup, and just perform `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` in the shell to get access to postgis features?  Or do I need to add a postgis database separately, like below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': password,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
    'geodata': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
         'NAME': 'geodjango',
         'USER': 'geo',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can keep using the default postgres setup, just changing the engine to: [django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#configure-settings-py)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': password,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah so I am guessing `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis` is an extension that includes everything in `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` plus geo-specific features?

Comment: You're right. django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis just extends django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 to add the PostGiS types.